# Normalized tight frame that is not orthonormal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, wavelets

Does anybody know an example of a normalized tight frame (wavelet frame) that is not an orthonormal frame of $L^2( \mathbb{R})$?

So in other words $\{\psi_{j,k}(x):=2^{j/2}\,\psi(2^j\,x-k)\}_{j,k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is supposed to be a frame satisfying $||f||^2_2  = \sum_{j,k} |\langle f , \psi_{j,k} \rangle|^2 , $ but the $\psi_{j,k}$ shall not form an ONB.

I am looking for such an example in the literature, but so far I did not find one.

Comment: You mean $\|f\|_2^2$, don't you? For $f=\psi_{m,n}$ you then get $\|\psi_{m,n}\|_2^2= \sum_{j,k} |\langle \psi_{m,n},\psi_{j,k}\rangle|^2 = \|\psi_{m,n}\|_2^2 + \sum_{(j,k)\neq (n,m)} |\langle \psi_{m,n},\psi_{j,k}\rangle|^2 $ so that $\langle \psi_{m,n},\psi_{j,k}\rangle=0$ for all $(j,k)\neq (n,m)$.

Comment: yes, there was a typo, but $\langle \psi_{m,n} , \psi_{j,k} \rangle = \delta_{m,j} \delta_{k,n}$ is only supposed to be true in the ONB case of couse and not for the case that I want to have an example for.

Comment: My comment intended to show that the condition on the norms *implies* orthogonality.

Answer (score 1):

We call $\{f_n\}$ a normalized tight frame for a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ if the sequence is a tight frame and all elements have norm one. Now, for any $f_n$ write 
$$\|f_n\|^2= \sum_m |\langle f_n, f_m\rangle|^2 = \|f_n\|^4+ \sum_{m\neq n} |\langle f_n, f_m\rangle|^2$$
Since the frame is normalized, i.e, each element has norm one, then from the above equation we can conclude that for all $n\neq m$ we have $\langle f_n, f_m\rangle= 0$. This means that the elements are orthogonal too. Therefore **any normalized tight frame is an orthonormal set**. It is also **basis** because it is complete.